# Linux Laptop shutting down on battery level bellow 8%

Tags: linux, crontab

I've written a `crontab` entry that runs a script in my home directory as user. That notifies me if I forgot to switch the power brick on. This works fine.

```
BATTERY=$(upower -e | grep 'BAT')
BATTERY_PERCENTAGE=$(upower -i $BATTERY|grep percentage|awk '{ print $2 }'|sed s/'%'/''/g)
AC_STATUS=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online)

echo "Battery: $BATTERY_PERCENTAGE %"


if [ "$BATTERY_PERCENTAGE" -lt "20" ]  && 
[     "$AC_STATUS" -eq "0"             ]; then

   notify-send --urgency=critical "WARNING: Battery is about to die"  "Plug in the power cable"
   mplayer samsung_low_battery_sound.mp4 &> /dev/null 

fi
```

My problem is that I don't want another root crontab entry, to check if the battery and AC is switched off, to automatically shutdown the laptop if it is on 5%. Rather would prefer to use the existing script. But the shutdown command needs root access. Is it possible to auto-shutdown as user via script? (The desktop allows this)

Will

Comment: if you're asking if it's possible to auto run a script as root, then i'm fairly sure that you can run the script with the sudo command and add an exception to the sudoers file of not needing a password for that perticular action (been awhile since i've done that though, so I can't remember exactly how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **not on systemd**, the command to shut down your system without `root` privileges is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
```

If you are on **systemd**, then `systemd` itself controls access to DBUS. You can read how to deal with this on the Arch Linux wiki page on [Allow users to shutdown](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/allow_users_to_shutdown#Users_without_sudo_privileges), which offers several solutions.

Alternatively, this can be achieved by changing `polkit` rules, which is a tad more complex, see once again the Arch Linux wiki page on [Polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Disable_suspend_and_hibernate).